# Assistance with Java Methods

Tags: java

I am confused as to where to use the following methods:

```
initialize(alpha);
print(alpha);
```

I did the below program and I'm getting the info I want, but I have no clue how to use these methods to change the code but get the same output. Perhaps I'm looking too much into it? Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProgEx_Ch9_No1{

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);    

public static void main(String[] args){

    double[] alpha = new double[50];

    for(int i=0; i<alpha.length; i++){

        alpha[i] = Math.pow(1,2);
        System.out.println("Alpha[" + i + "]: " + alpha[i]);

        if(i < 25){
            alpha[i] = Math.pow(1,2);
            System.out.println("Alpha[" + i + "]: " + alpha[i]);
        }
        else{
            alpha[i] = i*3;
            System.out.println("Alpha[" + i + "]: " + alpha[i]);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<alpha.length; i++){
        System.out.print(alpha[i] + " ");
        if ((i + 1)%10 == 0)
            System.out.println();

}

}
}
```

Comment: If you're getting what you want, why would you change it?

Comment: What are those methods? Are they part of a library? If so which library? Isn't the methods documented? It looks to me like an example from a book... If that is the case do read itm I'm sure it will have a reasonable explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double[] alpha = initialize();

    print(alpha);        

}

private static double[] initialize() {

    double[] alpha = new double[50];

    for(int i=0; i<alpha.length; i++)
    {
        alpha[i] = Math.pow(1,2);
        System.out.println("Alpha[" + i + "]: " + alpha[i]);

        if(i < 25)
        {
            alpha[i] = Math.pow(1,2);
            System.out.println("Alpha[" + i + "]: " + alpha[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            alpha[i] = i*3;
            System.out.println("Alpha[" + i + "]: " + alpha[i]);
        }
    }
    return alpha;
}

public static void print(double[] alpha) {
    for(int i=0; i<alpha.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(alpha[i] + " ");
        if ((i+ 1)%10 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it is a question on refactoring, so possibly you could have a method like:

```
public static double[] initialize(double[] alpha)
{
    for(int i=0; i<alpha.length; i++)
    {
        alpha[i] = Math.pow(1,2);
        System.out.println("Alpha[" + i + "]: " + alpha[i]);

        if(i < 25)
        {
            alpha[i] = Math.pow(1,2);
            System.out.println("Alpha[" + i + "]: " + alpha[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            alpha[i] = i*3;
            System.out.println("Alpha[" + i + "]: " + alpha[i]);
        }
    }

    return alpha;
}
```

You can then call this method from your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double[] alpha = new double[50];
    alpha = initialize(alpha);
    ....
}
```